# How to specify route dynamicly by route name in security.yaml?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4

I use Symfony4. I want to specify login page URL route by its route name, which is declared in `routes.yaml`

Now I have these lines in my `security.yaml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, allow_if: 'is_anonymous()'}
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

In my `routes.yaml` I have this:

```
login:
    path: /anyrouteiwant   
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login
```

What I want is to refer to route name 'login'

Comment: you can't do it in security.yaml,  you can try in the controller. check [symfony security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

Comment: Yes, I can. But then I should remove logic from security.yaml `access_control` to Controller's annotations. And write restriction to lower priority roles to every controller that should be `ROLE_USER+` accessible in case if I need to close all the pages for anonymous users. (Also, i dont want logged in users trap to login page). And, for sure, I can specify permission only for `anonymous` with dynamic reference to `login` in Controllers action

Comment: But it would be better to do this in security.yaml. `However, Thank you!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an environment variable?

`.env.dev` file (also test and prod)

```
LOGIN_PATH="/login"
```

`security.yaml` file

```
access_control:
    - { path: '^%env(LOGIN_PATH)%', allow_if: 'is_anonymous()'}
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

`routes.yaml` file:

```
login:
    path: '%env(LOGIN_PATH)%'
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login
```

don't know if it'll work but it should work.

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environment_variables.html#environment-variable-processors

Otherwise, it seems you can't reference a route configuration inside `security.yaml` file. To test it yourself, put:

```
var_dump($this->parameters);
```

inside `vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php line 71` just at the beginning of the `get($name)` method, you can see the defined parameters when you run:

```
php bin/console config:dump-reference security
```

command. And there doesn't seem a parameter defined in the parameterbag related with the defined routes.

Comment: Okay, this is an example of referring, but it's not what I want. I need to refer to variable in route.yaml, which is already declared.

Comment: testing this in `routes.yaml` with **Symfony 4.1** yields `\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException` `Using "%env(VARNAME)%" is not allowed in routing configuration` as introduced by the fixing of [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20682)

Comment: @vike, can you create a parameter sourced by the env, then use it inside the routes.yaml?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/service_container_parameters.html

Comment: @TahaPaksu, yes; defining `parameters:` `routename_name: routename`, & `routename_path: /routepath` in `services.yaml`, and using as `'%routename_name%':` `path: '%routename_path%'` in `routes.yaml`, it works (being dummy example aside), thanks. btw, I opted for annotations in my original wish to define a handle for *route* + *security* at a single point...